# Which one is the time standard format, C# or Objective-C?

Tags: c#, objective-c, datetime-format

We are developer clients for `Windows` and `Mac` using `C#` and `Objective-C`.
We need to support interaction between each other, and there are data communication between them.
One field of the data is time.

When using NSData to serialize the time it is following format:

```
2014-02-02 03:00:00 +0800
```

And using C#'s DateTime to serialize, we got:

```
2014-02-02 03:00:00 +08:00
```

And the output of `C#` cannot be parsed by `NSDate` in `Objective-C`, it treat the `+08:00` as minutes and seconds, instead of hours and minutes.

So which one is the standard, if `C#` one is standard, how can I parse it and serialize to it in `Objective-C`? And verse vice.

Comment: They're both "standard" for themselves. You can parse whatever format you like into a date object in either language. Just pick an interchange format for your project and use that.

Comment: Show your respective code that generates the two date strings and explain what format you want both of them to be. BTW - you may have better luck converting your dates to something like the number of seconds since a fixed epoch. This eliminates all of the headache of dealing with date strings.

Answer (score 2):

Convert to UTC to get rid of +08:00 and +0800